# How can I call or access a specific value in a combination of arrays and structures?

Tags: arrays, swift, function, struct

I had been given a rather odd homework by my senior which goes like below. This thread might be a little long and not the best way to be done, so giving the right direction to this or just telling me an alternative are both ok.

So this is how it works, there's this fantasy bank in which we have 3 types of coins and 3 types of foreign exchange to choose from. Both "Coin" and "Exchange" represent the basic information in a structure. There's a mutual structure called "Price" to be later used for price calls.

```
//Coin & Exchange:

//Exchange Struct:
struct Exchange {
    let name: String
    var price: Float?
    var date: Date?

//Initializers:
init(name: String, price: Float?, date: Date?) {
    self.name = name
    self.price = price
    self.date = date
    }
}

//Coin Struct:
struct Coin {
    let name: String
    var price: Float?
    var date: Date?

//Initializers:
init(name: String, price: Float?, date: Date?) {
    self.name = name
    self.price = price
    self.date = date
    }
}

//Price:

//Price Struct:
struct Price {
    let name: String
    var coin: [Coin]
    var exchange: [Exchange]

//Initializers:
init(name: String, coin: [Coin], exchange: [Exchange]) {
    self.name = name
    self.coin = coin
    self.exchange = exchange
    }
}
```

And here comes the ugly part where I'm supposed to put them all in an array which is also acceptable but a bit messy and basic. I'll try to make it more readable.

```
let pricesTime1: [Price] = 
[Price.init(name: "Coin Rate", coin: 

[
Coin.init(name: "Coin 1", price: 1_200_000, date: Date()), 
Coin.init(name: "Coin 2", price: 600_000, date: Date()), 
Coin.init(name: "Coin 3", price: 1_230_000, date: Date())
],

exchange: 
[
Exchange.init(name: "Exchange 1", price: 4_100, date: Date()), 
Exchange.init(name: "Exchange 2", price: 4_800, date: Date()), 
Exchange.init(name: "Exchange 3", price: 4_700, date: Date())])
]
```

And I've got 3 "pricesTime", similar but different in value and also a few in "nil".
The senior asked me to have a Function for minimum and maximum, first and last, and date of each "Coin" and "Exchange" value in these arrays given in a tuple. Don't mind the details nor the example itself, it was for the sake of my question info, but I really wanna know how to access/call "Coin 1 Price" for instance, or compare all price values of "Exchange" in order to make a min and max answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, a few tips:

Use `Exchange(name: String, price: Float?, date: Date?)` instead of `Exchange.init(name: String, price: Float?, date: Date?)`. It will make your code a bit more readable.

You may also want to rename the properties in your struct to reflect they are collections, ie: rename `coin` to `coins` and `exchanges` to `exchanges`.

As for accessing the `price` of a `Coin` given an `[Price]`, You can access it via subscripts as follows:

```
let pricesTime1: [Price] = [
   Price(name: "Coin Rate",
      coins: [
         Coin(name: "Coin 1", price: 1_200_000, date: Date()), 
         Coin(name: "Coin 2", price: 600_000, date: Date()), 
         Coin(name: "Coin 3", price: 1_230_000, date: Date())
      ],
      exchanges: [
         Exchange(name: "Exchange 1", price: 4_100, date: Date()), 
         Exchange(name: "Exchange 2", price: 4_800, date: Date()), 
         Exchange(name: "Exchange 3", price: 4_700, date: Date())
      ])
]

let priceTime1Price1Coin1Price = priceTimes[0].coins[0].price

// Or if you want to iterate over every coin price
for price in priceTimes {
   for coin in price.coins {
      print(coin.price)
   }
}
```

I could not grasp exactly what you are trying to accomplish. But I hope this can give you some help.

Good luck :)

Comment: Sorry for the delayed reply. Thank you, it really helped.